# installing plotutils in codeblocks

Tags: c++

I am a novice in c++ programming, and not at all experienced in graphics in any ways. I am trying to install plotutils package in codeblocks. I have downloaded and extracted the *plotutils-2.6.tar.gz* file available from https://www.gnu.org/software/plotutils/. But I don't know what to do next. The online manual does not give any detailed information regarding installation.

contents of the archive:
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1Upm.jpg)

I only want to use the plotter.h header file and its functions.

compiler: miniGW, IDE: code::blocks.

Comment: The file called `INSTALL` contains the instructions for installation. If you're using windows instead of *nix, I think (but don't remember) that cygwin is something to be used to allow _relatively_ pain-free running of the required configurations/make/install scripts.

Comment: @enhzflep i opened the INSTALL file, it tells me to run the _configure_ file. I try to run it using cmd, it says 'configure' is not a recognized command. How do I run "configure" file?

Comment: From what you've just said, it appears that you're using a windows-based system, right? If so, look into cygwin, like I said. You need a unix-like environment to run the tools required to configure the build process, Cygwin provides one that runs inside windows.

Comment: @enhzflep I did as you said. After installing cygwin I tried to proceed according to instructions, but when I give command './configure' I get the error   "configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See `config.log' for more details.".

Comment: Googling the text "configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH" seems to return a few results. Generally, they seem to advise the installation of gcc via a console command, all the ones I've seen so far have been using yum. You've already got a compiler, though it's a 'native' windows one. You might just run into issues with mixing of a POSIX library (plot-utils) with the rest of your project, unless you also use the cygwin environment to build your whole project. If you've the bandwidth, try using yum to install gcc, if not, perhaps you can setup the path. Not sure, <continued>

Comment: haven't used cygwin before, not really sure of all the ins and outs. :( **HOWEVER** - I just found this link, which might just be the far easier pathway to happiness: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/plotutils.htm (result of google search for "win build of plotutils")